# Converting Python Script back to a Graphic Model in QGIS Graphic Modeler

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-modeler

I created a model in the QGIS Graphic Modeler and exported it as a python script. I made a few changes in the python script and now want to export it back to the model. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible, there is no converter for this because in the script it is possible to perform functions like IF, CASE and LOOP that do not exist in the modeler logic.

For example: leave an empty entry and the process still works perfectly.
This is only possible with a script.